# Calculation of determinante via definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 4 & 5 & -1 \\ 3 & 7 & 1 & -2\\ 0 & 8 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & -1 & 3 & -1 \end{pmatrix}  $

I have to calculate determinante via definition(methode permutation). I think i will have 24 summands (4!=24), right? Can someone help me witg formul for it, because I cant find it on internet for matrix with n=4 and it is too complicated when I tried by myself and I never get right result.

For example for 3x3 formula is:    $a_{11}a_{22} a_{33} +a_{31} a_{12} a_{23} +a_{21} a_{32} a_{13} -a_{11} a_{32} a_{23} -a_{31} a_{22} a_{13} -a_{21} a_{12} a_{33}  $

How can i get formula for matrix 4x4?

Comment: There are much more efficient methods for finding a determinant.

Comment: Yes I know that. But I have to use thid method.

Comment: If you're really going to have to use the definition with the permutations, signs and all that then it is going to take quite a while, I'm afraid. Good luck, as carrying on two simple elementary operations on the matrix's rows you would get one much easier $\;3\times3\;$ matrix to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laplace's formula. You can get the determinant of your matrix by calculating the determinants of its minors. It is a quite handy formula, even for complicated 3x3.

Comment: But i have to use only this method..?

Comment: I'm not sure what method you mean, but your formula for the 3x3 is the rule of Sarrus, and it only works in 2x2 and 3x3.

Comment: @Agorf I think Ana means the formal, usual definition from linear algebra of a determinant. Look for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants

Comment: Ah do you mean the Leibniz formula? Edit: yea i just understood haha

Comment: Yes I mean using definition. But I am really confused now. Can you give me some directions? This on wiki doesnt help me a lot.

Comment: Yea it can get very confusing, i don`t think i can explain it better than the internet, but i can give you the permutations: http://fed.matheplanet.com/mprender.php?stringid=21892298&mixmod=mix